# Segmentation Fault : 11 Pointers and Structures

Tags: c, pointers, memory, struct

I have created two structs in my header file, one for Cards and one for Hands like so:

```
struct Card 
{                                 
    char *face; // define pointer face 
    char *suit; // define pointer suit
};


struct Hand
{
    struct Card *cards[15]; // define an array to hold a card
    char hand[13];  // defines the type of hand 
};
```

In my `printHand` function I am trying to add a card to each of the hands and then add those hands to an array representing all the players. I ran a debugger and the segmentation fault occurs here:

```
// Here we will add the cards to the array holding the player's hands
totalHands[indexHand].cards[indexCard]->face = shuffledDeck[indexCard].face;
totalHands[indexHand].cards[indexCard]->suit = shuffledDeck[indexCard].suit;
```

The debugger prints `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. Here is my function:

```
void printHand(struct Card* shuffledDeck, char* argv[])
{
    // total number of cards
    const int DeckMaxSize = 53;

    // get the command line input
    int numOfHands = atoi(argv[1]);
    int numOfCards = atoi(argv[2]);

    // counters for our loops
    int indexHand;
    int indexCard;

    struct Hand totalHands[10]; // an array holding all the hands

    // allocate memory for our struct
    struct Hand* tempHand = (struct Hand*)malloc(numOfCards * sizeof(struct Hand));

    // Adjusted the command line arguments if the number cards/hand and
    // players can not be resolved from a 52 sized deck
    int validateInput = DeckMaxSize / numOfHands;

    if (validateInput < numOfCards) {
        numOfCards = validateInput;
        printf("\n%s", "Input was adjusted to the size of the deck ( 52 )");
    }

    // Creates a new Hand and adds it to the totalHands[]
    for (indexHand = 1; indexHand <= numOfHands; indexHand++) {
        totalHands[indexHand] = *tempHand;
        printf("\n\n%s %d\n", "Player : ", indexHand);

        // add the cards to the hand and print each player's hand
        for (indexCard = 1; indexCard <= numOfCards; indexCard++) {
            // Here we will add the cards to the array holding the player's hands
            totalHands[indexHand].cards[indexCard]->face = shuffledDeck[indexCard].face;
            totalHands[indexHand].cards[indexCard]->suit = shuffledDeck[indexCard].suit;

            // Print all of our player's hand
            printf("\n%d %s ", indexCard, totalHands[indexHand].cards[indexCard]->face);
            printf("%s", totalHands[indexHand].cards[indexCard]->suit);
        }

        // print a new line for formatting
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(indexHand = 1; indexHand <= numOfHands; indexHand++){
...
for(indexCard = 1; indexCard <= numOfCards; indexCard++){
```

These loops go from `1` to `n`(max index including). But indexing should be from `0` to `n-1` . Therefore , these loops access index out of bounds .

Modify you loops to this -

```
for(indexHand = 0; indexHand < numOfHands; indexHand++){
...
for(indexCard = 0; indexCard < numOfCards; indexCard++){
```

### Edit -

```
 totalHands[indexHand].cards[indexCard]->face = shuffledDeck[indexCard].face;
totalHands[indexHand].cards[indexCard]->suit = shuffledDeck[indexCard].suit;
```

Before these both statements you don't allocate memory to array of pointer `cards` and yet you dereference it (*uninitialized pointers*).

Allocate memory pointers of this array and then access array members.

Comment: I thought so aswell but I am still receiving a segmentation fault.. the size of total hands (10) is way bigger then the input i pass which is 4. I also made the cards array in the struct size 15 but the max is 13 per player. So i really don't think it is an index of out of bounds issue. I believe it has to do with the pointers or the way I'm accessing them.

Comment: @LesterRamos Yes , maybe the case . I have updated the answer . Please take a look . Problem is the memory allocation which you need to do .

Comment: ahhh okay, i thought it would be taken care of when I would allocate the memory for the hand structure. So syntactically, how would i access the card array in the tempHand struct and allocate memory for it?

Comment: Using `tempHand` access the each pointer to `cards` in a loop and allocate memory to it using `malloc` .

Comment: i did it like so in the nested for loop but still receive that darn segmentations fault.                                                                                                      tempHand->cards[indexCard] = (struct Card*) malloc(numOfCards * sizeof(struct Card));

Comment: @LesterRamos Why using a nested loop  ?

Comment: not in the another nested loop but in the same one before the line I get the error at.

Comment: @LesterRamos Okay , but that will do a lot of allocation . Do you check `return ` of `malloc` if it was successful ?

Comment: ohhhhh yess! It would keep allocating memory every time the for loops ran which would be like 52 times... Thank you so much !

Comment: i upvoted your answer but until i get more points it won't show publicly, but thank you again!